# Stability of fixed points of $u_{n+1}=\frac15\left(4u_n+\frac3{u_n}-2\right)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Are the fixed points of
>   $$u_{n+1}=\frac15\left(4u_n+\frac3{u_n}-2\right)$$
>   where $n\in\Bbb N$, stable?

My friend and I are disagreeing but I haven't seen his work. I have obtained that the two fixed points are stable and my friend got one stable and one unstable. Who is right, if anyone?

Comment: To me, it looks like both are stable.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (4x + 3/x - 2)/5$.  The fixed points are the solutions of $f(x) = x$, namely $-3$ and $1$, at which $f'$ has the values $11/15$ and $1/5$ respectively.  Since these have absolute value $< 1$, they are stable.